# pure function assignment

Tags: dynamic, assignment, pure-function

I do not understand this statement from the [Introduction to Dynamic](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html#756925424) tutorial:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0}, 
 {Slider[Dynamic[x]], 
  Slider[Dynamic[1 - x, (x = 1 - #) &]]}
]
```

What happens when you set `x = 1 - #`?
Does that mean that `1 - x = #`? That doesn't make sense to me.

The resulting graphic has two sliders, it you select either one, the other goes in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

The second slider shows the value of $1-x$. When the slider position is changed, `Dynamic` attempts to update its argument (`1 - x`) with the new value from the slider. The problem is, however, that a value cannot be assigned *directly* to the expression `1 - x` (it is not a symbol), so the update would fail.

Instead, in the second argument of `Dynamic` you can provide a function that does that update by carrying out an assignment to the appropriate symbol whose value is being tracked, i.e. `x`. For that we need a function that, given the new position of the slider as input (i.e. the new value of $1-x$), calculates the new value of $x$ and assigns it to that symbol.

In this case, the second slider tracks an expression $y=1-x$. Moving the slider gives a new value of $y$. What is the corresponding new value of $x$? It is, of course, $1-y$. So, given $y$ as an argument to our "updating function", we have to 1. calculate this new value, and 2. explicitly assign it to $x$.

The calculation can be carried out by  `Function[{y}, 1 - y]` or, with slots, `1 - # &`. The function must also do the assignment to $x$, so we add that too: `(x = 1 - #)&`. Note that we need the parentheses because, without them, the expression would be interpreted as `x = (1 - # &)`, i.e. "assign this pure function to x".

In short, understand the second argument of `Dynamic` as providing the following information: "given the new value of the tracked expression, what variable should I update? And to what value should I update it?"

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I must say I find this concept hard to understand, but will study your answer and hope it eventually sinks in.

Comment: @Dave Can you point to the conceptual hurdle? I may not be making myself as clear, and perhaps I can provide an example if you can pinpoint a "missing link".

Comment: I guess what I don't see is: applying (x=1-#)& to say 1 (the current value of x from the first slider), you get x=0, then it  seems to me that 1-x is 1. But that is not how the second slider is working. Thank you for your help and persistance!